# Sort by price woocommerce by ID post_meta

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

There is an additional field in Posts (id_product), when using WP_Query I want to sort posts by meta _price (id_product).
How do I do this?

If I try to do so:

```
  $query->set( 'meta_key', '_price' );
  $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
  $query->set( 'order', 'desc');
```

Sorting is done not by _price, but by the number specified in post_meta